# Type Observable<boolean> is not assignable to type Observable<HttpResponse<boolean>>

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I'm working on an Angular 6 project, and while changing the code from using `Http` to `HttpClient`, I get the following error:

When I try to do:

```
 verifyEmail(email: string, verificationCode: string): Observable<HttpResponse<boolean>> {
    return this._http.get<boolean>(`${this.serviceUrl}emailVerification?email=${email}&verification_code=${verificationCode}`, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<boolean>) => {
        return resp.status === 204;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I get the error

```
Type Observable<boolean> is not assignable to type Observable<HttpResponse<boolean>>
```

Conversely, this:

```
deleteCollection(collection: Collection): Observable<HttpResponse<boolean>> {
    return this._http.delete<boolean>(this.serviceUrl + collection.id, this.requestOptionsResponse).pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<boolean>) => {
        return response.status === 204;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError),);
  }
```

reports no errors, with `this.requestOptionsResponse` as

```
private setRequestOptionsResponse() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept'      : 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    this.requestOptionsResponse = { headers: headers, observe: 'response', withCredentials: true}
}
```

Comment: with delete, your map is typed: `(response: HttpResponse<boolean>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to include `HttpResponse` in the type declaration:

```
verifyEmail(email: string, verificationCode: string): Observable<boolean> {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Strange, considering the official Angular documentation says  
  
`getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}`

Comment: @Aydex that refers to [reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) when the `observe` option is given.

Comment: Yeah, I'm giving that option in my requests, but I guess there's something I'm missing.